# TableAdapter selected GridView Row and insert?

Tags: c#, .net, tableadapter

I am trying to get something of a selected GridView Row which is controlled with TableAdapter. (Visual Studio 2010, ASP.NET)

I have otobas.xsd. Inside that, I have Otobus and Sefer tables and also SeferTableAdapter and OtobusTableAdapter. I fill the gridview like this;

```
otobasTableAdapters.SeferTableAdapter sef = new otobasTableAdapters.SeferTableAdapter();
        otobas.SeferDataTable sefs;
        sefs = sef.GetData();


        SeferTableAdapter sefers = new SeferTableAdapter();
        GridView1.DataSource = sefers.GetData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

On the GridView Table, I have Select buttons on each row, therefore, when the user clicks one of the select buttons, I want to know which row it was. And then, I want to get the row like this (however, I can't)

otobas.SeferRow rw = ...?

I don't know how to do that. I tried many things but I couldn't. After I get this rw, I want to do something like;

```
string id = rw['id'];
string arrival = rw['arrival'];
```

However, I just couldn't do it. Can you show me a way to do this?  I tried to add a row but I also couldn't do it. I don't know how to create a row I think. I tried to do the same as

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5ycd1034%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

but, when I wrote

otobas.SeferRow newRow = otobas... I have a data table named Sefer, but I can't reference it at all. Is it wrong to make an instance of the otobas dataset? Like

```
otobas oto = new otobas();

otobas.SeferRow sr = oto.Sefer.... ?
```

Why do I have to create an instance of otobas? I mean I already have it as otobas.xsd I just don't get it.

Comment: It compiled when I created an instance of otobas but the insert didn't make any change. Do I have to create an instance?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this before but is it possible to implement an event handler for the onlclick event of this grid (in either client side or server side code) where you can make use of the event arguments to find this an other information you are searching for>?